# Add dynamic number of calls to a deferred.promise queue

Tags: jquery, promise, queue, handler

I need guidance (not the code) on how to implement the following
I have a page with n products, each product has a matrix with available sizes and a method Update(idProduct) which is triggered when I am leaving each matrix.

I want to create a queue to execute each Update of the product matrix but only when the previous is finished since some updates can take some seconds.

So, I do not know how many times the Update method will be called.
The queue is dynamic since I do not know when someone is updating the product matrix.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I'm not convinced that updated should be done sequentially. Say you had several queued updates and the user leaves the page believing that they were complete or at least underway? From the client perspective, the fact that "some updates can take some seconds" isn't, on its own, reason to want them performed sequentially. If you are concerned about load on the server, then there's a case, but you would need to give the user a representation of the queue and/or inhibit leaving the page.

Comment: Yes, some blurry overlay/spinning wheel will be on top of each product while the Update is complete. And yes, I am concerned about overloading the server.